# Медиа запросы на расширение экрана

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.
Есть `<div class="top"></div>` не могу понять как сделать ему 3-4 медиа запроса.

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 1700px) {
    .top {
        margin-left:20%;
    }}
@media (max-width: 1800px) {
    .top {
        margin-left:22%;
    }}
@media (min-width: 1890px) {
    .top {
        margin-left:23%;
    }}
```

Последние 2 запроса работают, как нужно сделать, чтобы и первый начал работать?

```
@media (max-width: 1800px) {
```

Заменяет собой

```
@media (max-width: 1700px) {
```

Comment: Порядок измените. Первым максимальный размер и дальше по убыванию.

Comment: О спасибо большое, не знал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильная последовательность медиазапросов.

От меньшего к большему (min-width: 768px --> 992px --> 1200px):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ...
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  ...
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  ...
}
```

От большего к меньшему (max-width: 1200px --> 992px --> 768px):

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  ...
}    
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  ...
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  ...
}
```

*Мне такая схема помогает запомнить.*